# Valgrind leak detection returns segfault error

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am checking my code for memory leaks using Valgrind on Linux. The program runs fine for the first one hour, but returns the following error for some combination of directed edge. I am wondering if I need to check for NULL before dijkstra_sp.cpp executes. I have identified lines in the following code that could be at the center of this problem.

```
==25051== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==25051==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==25051==    at 0x410D79: List<DirectedEdge*>::addToList(DirectedEdge*, List<DirectedEdge*>*) (linked_list.h:76)
==25051==    by 0x410AD5: pathTo(DijkstraSPTree*, ShortestPath*, int) (dijkstra_sp.cpp:77)
==25051==    by 0x423C54: getShortestPath(EdgeWeightedDigraph*, int, int) (vehicle_searching.cpp:45)
==25051==    by 0x4187E5: netPathWeight(EdgeWeightedDigraph*, int, int, int) (vehicle_Linux.cpp:1099)
==25051==    by 0x41B8E0: Schedule(int, int, VehicleState*) (vehicle_Linux.cpp:781)
==25051==    by 0x415719: updateAndRender(VehicleState*, int) (vehicle_Linux.cpp:237)
```

dijkstra_sp.cpp

```
struct DirectedEdge {
  int32 from;
  int32 to;
  real32 weight;
};

void
pathTo(DijkstraSPTree *spTree, ShortestPath *shortestPath, int32 dest)
{
  // should I assert input not null? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  List<DirectedEdge *>::traverseList(freeDirectedEdge, shortestPath->edgeList);
  List<DirectedEdge *>::emptyList(&shortestPath->edgeList);
  shortestPath->totalWeight = spTree->distTo[dest];

  // check if there IS a path to dest from the root of spTree
  if (spTree->distTo[dest] < INFINITY) {
        DirectedEdge *nextEdge = spTree->edgeTo[dest];
        if(nextEdge != 0)
        nextEdge = spTree->edgeTo[nextEdge->from];
    for (DirectedEdge *nextEdge = spTree->edgeTo[dest];
        nextEdge != 0;
        nextEdge = spTree->edgeTo[nextEdge->from]) {
// FOLLOWING IS LINE 77 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      shortestPath->edgeList =
        List<DirectedEdge *>::addToList(nextEdge, shortestPath->edgeList);
    }
  }
```

linked_list.h

```
// item T to the list
template<typename T> List<T> *
List<T>::addToList(T newItem, List<T> *list)
{
// Could sizeof(List<T>) being zero cause this issue? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    List<T> *resultList = (List<T> *)malloc(sizeof(List<T>));
FOLLOWING IS LINE 76 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    resultList->item = newItem;
    resultList->next = list;
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: Just because your program crashed in one particular place, this doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Your bug can be anywhere. For example, unless `List<T>` is a POD, allocating it using `malloc()`, as the shown code does, is undefined behavior, and a guaranteed bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run out of memory.  The call to `malloc` returns NULL (0) when that happens.  When you try to write to that invalid pointer you get the crash.

Comment: I suspected this, so I am going to assign more memory to this program and see if it crashes. It works fine without Valgrind for smaller network of edges and vertices.

Comment: @Far For any serious program you should check the return value of `malloc` for `NULL` and exit gracefully with an error. Many simple apps just define a `safe_malloc` that does this and call that instead of `malloc`. With C++ you should be using `new` anyway. It will throw an exception when you're out of memory.

Comment: @Gene oh yes, I don't know why I forgot to check for `NULL` and use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`